# How can I declare a varbinary(MAX) in VIsual Studio?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

[image: SQL Table in Visual Studio 2010]

I have the table that you can see in the image (it's Visual Studio 2010), and I want to declare that last column as a varbinary(MAX). But in the 'length' field it only accepts numbers 1 to 8000.

Where/How can I change it to MAX?

Comment: VARBINARY(MAX) was introduced with sql server 2005. you need a newer Sql Server.

Comment: Probably because I have SQL Server 2005, but it's the Compact Edition. I'll look into that, thanks.